# How to pass values to base class using inheritance while validating forms

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 7, reactive form for validation. I try to create a base class to check validations which can be inherited by child components, this might reduce the time and codes. I try to reuse the codes.

**BaseClass**

```
class ErrorDisplayBaseClass{
    // this.form might be indicated by any decorator or formGroup.

    isFieldValid(field: string) {
         return !this.form.get(field).valid && this.form.get(field).touched;
    }
        
    displayFieldCss(field: string) {
      return {
        'has-error': this.isFieldValid(field),
        'has-feedback': this.isFieldValid(field)
      };
    }

    // few codes here for checking all fields are validated.
}
```

**ChildComponents**

```
export class UserAddComponent extends ErrorDisplayBaseComponent implements OnInit{
    private signupForm: FormGroup;
    
    ngOnInit() {   
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group(
         {
            firstname: ["",Validators.required],
            lastname: ["",Validators.required]
        })
    }

onSubmit(){ 
    // have to check the validation when submitting.
}
```

The child components may have different fields
**childComponent-html**

```
<div [ngClass]="displayFieldCss('firstname')">
    <app-error-display [displayError]="isFieldValid('firstname')" errorMsg="Please check your firstname"></app-error-display>
</div>
```

***app-error-display*** is another component which helps to display errors.

If I put ***isFieldValid(),displayFieldCss()*** inside the childComponent without using base class, it's working fine. But I need to copy and paste to all components. (Codes repeating). Is there any way to use a base component to check validation?

*Note : **this.form** might be indicated by any decorator or formGroup.*

Comment: When I read the line "return !this.form.get(field).valid && this.form.get(field).touched;" within isFieldValid I wonder why the first is negated? I believe you want to name it isFieldInvalid. Much confusion here.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I put in the note that i need to set that this.form, I couldn't understand who to define it. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: what doesn't work when using the base class?
Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Arikael I need to pass values and signupForm to the base class to check. I need to make sure that no need to write reusable codes.

Comment: yes, I got that, but I assumed you get an error when using the base class. Is this not the case and you're asking how you would properly use the base class?

Comment: I dont get any error, as you said I need to know how can I do with base class

Comment: why not just use `this.form = this.formBuilder.group(
         {
            firstname: ["",Validators.required],
            lastname: ["",Validators.required]
        })
    }`

or via constructor.

That's how we solved something similar

Comment: so how can i indicate 'form' in base class?

Comment: what do you mean by 'indicate'?